# Purchased 1980 home, exterior outlet not working

Tags: electrical

Story: purchased a home built in 1980.  One of the exterior outlets was missing.  As in, just exposed wiring (ground, white, black).  I installed a new receptacle but it doesn't work.  Theres an interior outlet nearby but not exactly opposite of the problem exterior outlet.  I checked out the interior outlet and it has two sets of wiring thats daisy chained but It seems to be chained to an adjacent interior outlet.  (Tested by unhooking the black wire and an adjacent interior outlet stopped working).  Anybody have any idea what the problem could be?  I don’t know how exterior outlets are wired(straight to circuit breaker?).   If anybody has any insight, I would be grateful! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is there a tripped GFCI somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately, not

Comment: Was the wiring literally exposed? Or was it capped with wire nuts and covered with a blank plate? If it was literally exposed then it is quite possible that for safety's sake the other end of the wires (either at another receptacle, at the main breaker panel or some other junction box) were disconnected.

Comment: The wires were exposed but tucked into the box neatly.  I took a look at the breaker panel and it doesnt look like anything is disconnected.  I’m starting to think the previous owner possible cut it to use for another purpose? That would just be weird though

Comment: Be sure the outlet you installed *is* GFCI. Look for a switch in the house that controls the outlet.

Comment: Check real good may be off for reason ,

Comment: Did you check the wires with a voltage tester before installing the new outlet?  To me it sounds like you just wired an outlet without knowing for sure you even disconnected the correct breaker!  

You can't just guess and assume which circuit that outside wire branches off of. Do you have any chance of following the wire through the wall anywhere? (like does it run into a basement where you can see it?)  Pull on the wires a little, maybe they're disconnected and pull right out of the wall.

Comment: You don't need to use a GFCI outlet, there just needs to be a GFCI device upstream conferring its protection.  In fact, a GFCI outdoors is a bad idea; despite "rainproof" covers, the weather tears them up.

Comment: Thanks for the concern. I turned all off all breakers before installing the new receptacle.  I just purchased a wire tracer.  Should be arriving in the mail soon.  Will update.  Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 3):

The fact of the wires being left in the box *but not capped* is practically proof that they are not hooked up to anything on the other end.

The reason is, no sane person would energize wires that are just tucked into a box without capping.  In fact I believe energizing a set of wires to nothing is a code violation, even if they are capped.  Which they are not.

So it'll be a bit of a bug hunt to find the other end of this cable.

Comment: Sounds like youre right.  Just ordered a wire tracer.  We’ll see where this rabbit leads me

Answer (score 0):

In 1980, a single GFCI was commonly used for all bathroom outlets as well as exterior outlets. In other words, you probably have only one GFCI for the house. If this is the case and the bathroom outlets are live, then the wires feeding your exterior outlet are probably disconnected. Start looking in the outlet boxes in your bathrooms for disconnected wires.

Comment: There is a backyard outlet that is connected to the same circuit as the bathroom.  It works...but the other outdoor one does not.  I checked the boxes and they look all connected.

Comment: my tracer came in and I traced the wire to another outdoor receptacle (on the opposite side of the house) that was covered up and unused.  I opened it up and there was only one 14/2 cable.  I followed the tracer and it seems like the wire is running above windows not near any receptacles.  I put the tracer near any receptacles to make sure and it didn’t make any noise.  The wire does cross-by the breaker but I cant tell whats going on around there because of interference in the signal.  I’m perplexed.   Do you have any idea? Thank you